# How do I execute alley-oop on PC?

Tags: pc, nba2k14

My keyboard configuration is :

ESDF for movement. (WASD adjusted to the right)

Num **1** - Block/Rebound.    **2** - Shot stick (down)    **3** - Shot stick (left) 
 **4** - Pass.
Num **5** - Shoot/Steal
  **6** - Shot stick (right)   **7** - Screen/Charge      **8** - Shot stick (up)
Num **9** - Intense D/Modifier     Space - Sprint.

I don't remember the controller settings but I know some of it were :

Shots/Isomotion(2-4-6-8 are used for shooting, dribbling moves with modifier)
All the pass and shooting are camera relative.

Answer (score 2):

When using a game pad it's a combo of pass and steal pressed together and I believe the directional stick has to be pointing to the basket. With you keyboard setup it would be **4** & **5** pressed together.